# custom CSS properties strangely overwriting themselves in simple demo

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I wrote a really [simple element to validate a form](https://github.com/mercmobily/hot-form-validator/tree/v0.1.3), and wrote full demo for it. To see it, just do `bower install hot-form-validator` and see the demo with `polymer serve`.

I am having a strange issue, as in the demo the paper-toast are coming out in the wrong color.

Here is the source of the demo. Please only consider the first three snippets. Look at line 88, 119 and 149.

It seems like only the last setting of the property is taken. However, since the target of the rule is a Polymer element, it should be ale to hold the value...

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>hot-form-validator demo</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-pages-shared-styles.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-snippet.html">

    <link rel="import" href="../hot-form-validator.html">

    <!-- devDependencies -->
    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-form/iron-form.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../paper-input/paper-input.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <script src="../../sinonjs/sinon.js"></script>

    <style is="custom-style" include="demo-pages-shared-styles">

      :root {
        paper-toast {
          --paper-toast-background-color: green;
          --paper-toast-color: white;
        };
        paper-toast#secondGlobalToast {
          --paper-toast-background-color: blue;
          --paper-toast-color: white;
        };
        paper-toast#errorGlobalToast {
          --paper-toast-background-color: red;
          --paper-toast-color: white;
        };
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <paper-toast id="firstGlobalToast"></paper-toast>
    <paper-toast id="secondGlobalToast" class="second"></paper-toast>
    <paper-toast class="error" id="errorGlobalToast"></paper-toast>


    <script>
      sinon.log = function( m ){console.log("Message:", m)};
      //var server = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest()
      server = sinon.fakeServerWithClock.create();
      //server.autoRespond = true;
      server.respondImmediately = true;

      server.respondWith(
        'POST',
        'submit_validating', [
          200,
          'application/json',
          '{"name":"nameField","surname":"surnameField"}'
        ]
      );

      server.respondWith(
        'POST',
        'submit_not_validating', [
          422,
          'application/json',
          '{"message":"Unprocessable Entity","errors":[{"field":"maker","message":"Maker is not acceptable"}]}'
        ]
      );
    </script>

    <h1>Local toasts</h1>

    <div class="vertical-section-container centered">
      <h3>Basic hot-form-validator, passing</h3>
      <demo-snippet>
        <template>

          <style is="custom-style">
              paper-toast {
                --paper-toast-background-color: white; /* This is overwritten by line 149?!? */
                --paper-toast-color: white;
              };
              paper-toast#errorToast {
                --paper-toast-background-color: red;
                --paper-toast-color: white;
              };
          </style>

          <hot-form-validator sane-submit error-toast-id="errorToast">
            <paper-toast id="firstToast"></paper-toast>
            <paper-toast id="errorToast"></paper-toast>
            <form id="form" is="iron-form" method="POST" action="submit_validating">
              <paper-input name="maker" id="maker" ></paper-input>
              <paper-input name="model" id="model"></paper-input>
              <paper-button type="submit" raised>Submit!</paper-button>
            </form>
          </hot-form-validator>

        </template>
      </demo-snippet>
    </div>


    <div class="vertical-section-container centered">
      <h3>Basic hot-form-validator, failing</h3>
      <demo-snippet>
        <template>

          <style is="custom-style">
              paper-toast {
                --paper-toast-background-color: green;
                --paper-toast-color: white;
              };
              paper-toast#errorToast {
                --paper-toast-background-color: red; /* This is overwritten by line 149?!? */
                --paper-toast-color: white;
              };
          </style>

          <hot-form-validator sane-submit error-toast-id="errorToast">
            <paper-toast id="firstToast"></paper-toast>
            <paper-toast id="errorToast"></paper-toast>
            <form id="form" is="iron-form" method="POST" action="submit_not_validating">
              <paper-input name="maker" id="maker" ></paper-input>
              <paper-input name="model" id="model"></paper-input>
              <paper-button type="submit" raised>Submit!</paper-button>
            </form>
          </hot-form-validator>

        </template>
      </demo-snippet>
    </div>

    <div class="vertical-section-container centered">
      <h3>Basic hot-form-validator, using specified toast element, passing</h3>
      <demo-snippet>
        <template>

          <style is="custom-style">
              paper-toast {
                --paper-toast-background-color: gray; /* THIS influences line 119 */
                --paper-toast-color: white;
              };
              paper-toast#secondToast {
                --paper-toast-background-color: blue;
                --paper-toast-color: white;
              };
              paper-toast.errorToast {
                --paper-toast-background-color: purple;
                --paper-toast-color: white;
              };
          </style>

          <hot-form-validator sane-submit toast-id="secondToast" error-toast-id="errorToast">
            <paper-toast id="firstToast"></paper-toast>
            <paper-toast id="secondToast"></paper-toast>
            <paper-toast id="errorToast"></paper-toast>
            <form id="form" is="iron-form" method="POST" action="submit_validating">
              <paper-input name="maker" id="maker" ></paper-input>
              <paper-input name="model" id="model"></paper-input>
              <paper-button type="submit" raised>Submit!</paper-button>
            </form>
          </hot-form-validator>

        </template>
      </demo-snippet>
    </div>

    <h1>Global toasts</h1>

    <div class="vertical-section-container centered">
      <h3>Basic hot-form-validator, using global toast element, passing</h3>
      <demo-snippet>
        <template>

          <hot-form-validator sane-submit global-toast error-toast-id="errorGlobalToast">
            <form id="form" is="iron-form" method="POST" action="submit_validating">
              <paper-input name="maker" id="maker" ></paper-input>
              <paper-input name="model" id="model"></paper-input>
              <paper-button type="submit" raised>Submit!</paper-button>
            </form>
          </hot-form-validator>

        </template>
      </demo-snippet>
    </div>

    <div class="vertical-section-container centered">
      <h3>Basic hot-form-validator, using global toast element, failing</h3>
      <demo-snippet>
        <template>

          <hot-form-validator sane-submit global-toast error-toast-id="errorGlobalToast">
            <form id="form" is="iron-form" method="POST" action="submit_not_validating">
              <paper-input name="maker" id="maker" ></paper-input>
              <paper-input name="model" id="model"></paper-input>
              <paper-button type="submit" raised>Submit!</paper-button>
            </form>
          </hot-form-validator>

        </template>
      </demo-snippet>
    </div>

    <div class="vertical-section-container centered">
      <h3>Basic hot-form-validator, using specified global toast element, passing</h3>
      <demo-snippet>
        <template>

          <hot-form-validator sane-submit global-toast toast-id="secondGlobalToast" error-toast-id="errorGlobalToast">
            <form id="form" is="iron-form" method="POST" action="submit_validating">
              <paper-input name="maker" id="maker" ></paper-input>
              <paper-input name="model" id="model"></paper-input>
              <paper-button type="submit" raised>Submit!</paper-button>
            </form>
          </hot-form-validator>

        </template>
      </demo-snippet>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think your template sections are scoped how you think and that's why the last definition wins.  I'd suggest adding more differentiation to the paper-toast elements for each section so you can "select" those and only those.

Comment: I think you are right... Please add it as an answer!